# В чем разница между формами в Angular (4) (Reactive, Dynamic, Template-driven) и в каких ситуациях каждая из них нужна?

Tags: angular2, forms, angular4

Не так давно начал изучать Angular 4, до этого не сталкивался, и появилась задача создать добавление записей на бэкенд, функции все работают, но когда дошло дело до самих форм, оказалось что их есть несколько. На angular.io мне не очень понятна документация на эту тему, поэтому решил спросить у опытных разработчиков тут.

В частности меня интересует почему создали три вида форм и для каких задач?

За любую информацию буду очень благодарен.